# Java write to file. Using a loop

Tags: java, string, file

I have a simple application that yet would trash a text file (it's just practice) I'm only 3 days with Java yet. Problem is there are no errors until you run the program then it throws an exception and stops. Thank you.
This is the exception:

```
      java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
    at test.main(test.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at 
     edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

And this is the code.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.IOException;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final String alphabet = "abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        final int N = alphabet.length();
        Random r = new Random();

        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("hello.txt");
        String sb = " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < 1;) {
            sb += alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(N));
            System.out.println(sb);
            int length = sb.length();
            file.write(sb);
            file.close();
            if (length == 30) {
                sb = " ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ;) When you ask a question about an exception, please show the stacktrace.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: What kind of exception? Please edit your post and add the stacktrace.

Comment: Can you post the output so people can understand what error you are experiencing?

Comment: Your for loop does not increment i. In fact its condition also looks strange

Comment: First rule of programming: read the error message.

Comment: Offtopic: Classnames should start with a capital letter. That's a widely accepted convention.

Comment: Read the [Java IO tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/). streams should always be closed in a finally block, or the [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement should be used to do that for you.

Comment: You have `file.close()` inside the loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you are closing your `FileWriter` and trying to use it again.

Instead, close the writer after you've finished the loop:

```
try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("hello.txt")) {
  String sb = " ";
  for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {  // Note: added a i++
    sb += alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(N));
    System.out.println(sb);
    int length = sb.length();
    file.write(sb);
    // file.close();   <---- NOPE: don't do this
    if (length == 30) {
      sb = " ";
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks to [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380558/java-write-to-file/18380633#comment26990914_18380558) for spotting the `i++` omission.

Comment: Note that the loop is still only executing once with that condition. For i = 0

Answer (score 3):

Actual writing **while** being in a loop **will not** take place unless you call file.**flush()** method.

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("hello.txt");
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         fileWriter.write(line);
         fileWriter.flush();
    }
} finally {
     fileWriter.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FileWriter file = new FileWriter("hello.txt");
    String sb =  " ";

   for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        sb += alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(N));
        System.out.println(sb);
        int length = sb.length();
        file.write(sb);
        file.close();
        if(length == 30){
            sb = " ";
        }
    }
```

You are initializing  FileWriter once and closing it in the 1st iteration itself then trying to use it again in next iteration. Hence you are getting an Exception.

I recommend put your for loop in try statement and close your FileWriter in finally statement. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) is oracle tut on try-catch-finally construct.

Final code will go something like below

```
    FileWriter file = null;
    try {
        try {
            file = new FileWriter("hello.txt");
            String sb = " ";
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                sb += alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(N));
                System.out.println(sb);
                int length = sb.length();
                file.write(sb);
                if (length == 30) {
                    sb = " ";
                }
            }
        } finally {
            file.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your should close the FileWriter outside the for loop.

```
file.close();
```

Another problem with your code is that no increment is done on *i* in the loop. Thus it is a infinite loop and you program won't stop(after resolving the exception). Try something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
```

or add a break condition within the body.

Answer (score 1):

When you  close the file as in the following line

```
 file.close()
```

it means you are done working with the file.

In your case you close the file in the loop which means the next iteration will throw an exception.

Move the above mentioned code out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Only close your FileWriter stream once you are completely done using it.

Also, the write method for FileWriter does not include a method for only a String parameter. That might be the garbage you are getting when reading the file.